# Showing strings in ListView columns dynamically - not working

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My goal is the following: 
[The user enters the stuff as shown in this picture. The 3 items (*source file*, *destination directory* and *if file exists*) are saved in a string array. User clicks OK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guth5.png)

[After clicking OK the previous window is closed and the user is taken to the main form shown in this picture. The previously mentioned *source file* and the *destination directory* are shown in the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSnlB.png)

I am using the following code to show the entered file & directory in the table:

```
    private void okButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //saving user's input
        userInput = new string[3];
        userInput[0] = sourceFileTextBox.Text;
        userInput[1] = destinationDirComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        userInput[2] = ifFileExistsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //creating a new ListView object - the object is derived from the ListView Class 
       and has absolutely nothing in the constructor or anywhere
       Classes.ListViewDerivative lvd = new Classes.ListViewDerivative();
       ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(userInput[0]);
       item1.SubItems.Add(userInput[1]);
       lvd.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
       this.Hide();
    }
```

It doesn't work. The table is empty no matter where I put this code - I've tried to put this adapted code in the ListViewDerivative constructor, a function in the ListViewDerivative Class and in the editFileEntry(first picture) class. The right text is saved in the array but is not shown in the table. Please help!

Comment: Did you add the necessary Columns to your ListView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the lvd variable is not used anywere. You have to add the 'lvd' -control to your mainview. You can use the Designer for this and in the Dialog Result of your "FilePickerDialog" you can assign the results to your datagrid.

some pseudo code for your MainView

```
void    Config_Clicked()
{
   ConfigDlg dlg = new ConfigDlg();
   if(dlg.ShowDialog() == OK)
   {
       this.myListView1.Items.Add(dlg.userInput[0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: great to hear ;-) I wouldn't expect that from all my pseudo code ^^